# forEach clause to iterate through indexes of a Vector

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, vector, foreach

I have a method like this:

```
public void addVector(Vector myVector) {
    if (myVector == null) {
        return;
    }

    Collection<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
        values.add(((String[]) myVector.get(i))[1]);
    }

    this.addItems(values);
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to make a forEach clause from that.
Is it possible to itereate through the indexes [i] in a forEach loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the index if you use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (Object obj : myVector) {
    values.add(((String[]) obj)[1]);
}
```

Of course it would be better to use a parameterized type (`Vector<String[]>`) and avoid the casting.

Or if you meant the actual `forEach` method:

```
myVector.forEach(o -> values.add(((String[]) o)[1]));
```

or, even better, use `Stream` with `collect` instead of `forEach`:

```
List<String> values = 
    myVector.stream()
            .map(o -> (String[]) o)[1])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just do

```
 List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(myVector);
```

*update*

If the vector contains String arrays they need to be mapped

```
List<String> values = myVector.stream().map(arr -> { return arr.length <= 1 ? null : arr[1];}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This works if OP were using `Vector<String>`, but the OP appears to be using `Vector<String[]>` (but as a raw type). The desired result appears to be a list containing each `String` located at index `1` of each array.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the indices, you can simply iterate over values, like this:

```
vector.forEach(el -> values.add(((String[]) el)[1]));
```